# Card game framework Python 2.6 help/guidance

Tags: python, arrays

I need some guidance as to where to begin in this assignment.  We have to make a program that simply keeps track of where each card is sent from a deck to either a player, a computer, or if it is still in the deck.

My professor gave us starter code that we must use and are not allowed to alter

```
""" cardGame.py
basic card game framework
keeps track of card locations for as many hands as needed
"""
from random import *

NUMCARDS = 52
DECK = 0
PLAYER = 1
COMP = 2

cardLoc = [0] * NUMCARDS
suitName = ("hearts", "diamonds", "spades", "clubs")
rankName = ("Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", 
        "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King")
playerName = ("deck", "player", "computer")

def main():
   clearDeck()

for i in range(5):
   assignCard(PLAYER)
   assignCard(COMP)

showDeck()
showHand(PLAYER)
showHand(COMP)
```

I have some ideas as to what I want each of the functions, showDeck(),showHand(PLAYER),showHand(COMP), and a small idea for the clearDeck() function.  I just need some guidance as to whether this will require the creation of a class, or simply using arrays (lists in python as I've read) to keep track of each card.  I also would appreciate some help with how to create a deck from which all the cards are tracked.  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
deck = [(cardval,suitval) for suitval in range(4) for cardval in range(13)] 
deck.shuffle()
```

would work I think... classes may make it more idiomatic ... but you certainly can do it with just arrays/lists dicts/ etc

a good example would be

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self,cardval,suitval):
       self.cardval = cardval
       self.suitval = suitval
    def __str__(self):
       return "%s of %s"%(rankName[self.cardval],suitName[self.suitval])
    def __repr__(self):
       return "Card <%s>"%self

print Card(0,2) #prints "ace of Spades"
deck = [Card(cardval,suitval) for suitval in range(4) for cardval in range(13)] 
print deck
```

Comment: Could you explain the main difference between lists and dictionaries, from what I understand dictionaries store a type of data that can be altered, while lists are somewhat static and are only changed when it's done inside the program.  We haven't really covered dictionaries in class much

Comment: dictionaries are just key/value pairings ... much like hash tables in other languages `variable[key] = value` for example `my_dict['cards'] = 'A234567890JQK'`